# Where are the item dialogue boxes in OS X?

Tags: modeling, osx

I thought Blender would work the same on a Mac as it does on a PC, but I cannot seem to find the item 'dialogue boxes' that exist on the PC version. Anyone know how to bring up an item dialogue box in OSX version of Blender?

Comment: What do you mean by dialogue boxes? can you post an image of the missing item?

Comment: On a PC version, you right click an object (like a cube or cylinder) and can bring up a dialogue box to edit the number of vertices, etc.  Can't find a similar thing on the Mac version. Can't post a picture of it because I can't find it?  Thanks

Comment: awesome. thanks.  I will give that a try when I get back to it.  thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>T</kbd> to open the Toolbox.

<kbd>N</kbd> for the Properties

<kbd>F6</kbd> to bring the poup-up (that shows the same options as the ones on the Toolbox).

[image]

If the keyboard shortcuts conflict with the ones in blender you can re-assign them using the **User Properties** (or better still by changing the preferences on your OS)